# This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have an ASP.NET MVC app (running on .NET 4.8). Runs fine on my dev server. I publish the app, it runs, I'm able to login. Then I get the following:

```
This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!
```

I do have the file in my root and it's called `PrecompiledApp.config`.

```
<precompiledApp version="2" updatable="false"/>
```

How do I fix this? I have never seen this before anywhere.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *How do I fix this?* Why *fix* it ? Does it cause any issues, problems?